# Reporting Services: DateTime parameter not showing the time part when its midnight

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, format

I need to add a 'StartDate' parameter to a report in Reporting Services 2005, which should represent the current date, at midnight.

If I use Now() as expression, it will correctly use midnight in the calculations, but to the user, the time part will not be shown.

13/12/2011

which can be confusing because then the user doesn't really realise he or she can type in a time part.

*How can I format this date to the following:
13/12/2011 00:00 
**while keeping the parameter as a DateTime datatype**.***?**

Edit: I've checked the duplicate question and tried to apply it to my case, but run into the following phenomenom:

If I try:

```
=DateTime.Parse(Format(Now().Date().AddSeconds(1), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Then the parameter shows "14/12/2011 00:00:01" which is confusing for the users, so I then tried the following:

```
=DateTime.Parse(Format(Now().Date().AddSeconds(1), "d/M/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

But then the parameter shows "14/12/2011" again! In other words, the time part is gone again!

Who invented this stuff? :P

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615090/show-time-tag-in-ssrs-parameter

Comment: Thanks, I tried to apply the solution of the other question, but didn't work 100%. See edit to my original question.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula with .Parse(Format(... causes redundant work that is messing things up. Try this:

```
=Now().Date().AddSeconds(.001)
```

Comment: True, but this solution still displays "14/12/2011" and not the time part :(

Comment: hmm. Seems like we found a difference between 2005 and 2008R2.

Comment: Ok, since the answer seems to be "doesn't work in SSRS 2005", I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Format`. For example: `Format(Parameters!SelectedDate.Value, "d/M/yyyy HH:mm")`

[Here](http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/date-formatting-in-reporting-services-list-of-format-codes/) is a list of `DateTime` identifiers for use with `Format`.

**Edit:**

I get it now, you want 00:00 to show up in the parameter input calendar in the report viewer. The time part won't show up when it's set to midnight. [This is by design](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/ad269830-c02a-47bf-b2ba-29a8cfa0cf80). If you're using 2005 or earlier, Jamie's solution won't work and you're stuck.

Comment: I tried that, but format creates a string, and I would like the datatype of the parameter to stay a DateTime to avoid unnecessary conversions.

Comment: Format does not change the type of the parameter. I see from the edit that you're parsing it back in to a `DateTime`. Why? This is very confusing and it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What exactly do you mean by "parameter"? Your code is not working with any report parameters. In fact, from your edit, it appears you are trying to simply post the current date with "00:00" appended to the end. I have updated my answer with a way to do this.

Comment: Sorry about any confusion. I'm delaring Report Parameters of which one is a startdate, I want it to be of DateTime type, so that I don't need to do any converting in the actual report query.
Format() *does* seem to change the parameter type, because when I used it, it complains about the parameter being the wrong type (string when datetime is expected).